# Unmodified files also copied to target directory in inria spoon transformation

Tags: spoon, inria-spoon

I have written source code transformation using inria-spoon library. I have the following function in my transformer (which makes sure that my "process" function is invoked only for desired classes):

```
public boolean isToBeProcessed(CtInterface<?> ctClass) {
        return isProcessible(ctClass);
    }
```

So only desired classes are transformed. But it seems that all the classes are copied from source directory to target directory. I expect only the transformed classes to be copied to target directory.

Is there some configuration OR handling for this in inria-spoon?

Currently I am invoking my transformer via JUnit test case, using following function:

```
public void testTransform()
    {
        final String[] arguments = { "-i", "E:/input",
                "-o", "E:/output", "-p",
                "com.transformer.ClassTransformer",
                "-c"};

        final Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
        launcher.setArgs(arguments);
        launcher.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option `[(-f|--generate-files) <generate-files>]`, also available with the API, seems to be what you want.

Comment: thanks @martin-monperrus ....but this option expects me to provide the list of files that are to be modified. It will not work for me.

Comment: you can also use wildcards